# How to know all the fragment Execution has been done

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt, update-attributes

I have the following flow :

[image]

following is the Explanation of Flow

1- I have large file that i am splitting by splitRecord Processor into multiple fragment .

2- All the fragment is passing through ExecuteStream command processor . The processor is doing some processing on all the fragment

3- The processing of data on Execute command processor can be fail or can be passed too .

4- At the end how can i know All the fragment has been processed (it could be either fail or pass)

I am expecting the appropriate result by using nifi processor

Comment: Can you please show what did you try and how so far ?